# My where statement with a JSON_extract function on a nullable column is confirmed when said column's value is NULL?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I have a where statement with a JSON_extract method in it. The JSON_extract uses a nullable column called `new_value` or `old_value`. The check works if the column contains a JSON string, but when the column is NULL the where statement gets confirmed.

```
->where(function($query) use ($other_key, $new_change) {
        $query->where(DB::raw('json_extract(old_value, "$.theme_id") = 1))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw('json_extract(new_value, "$.theme_id") = 1));
```

When the `new_value` or the `old_value` is NULL the row gets returned, but the theme_id of NULL obviously isn't equal to 1. Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
->where(function($query) use ($other_key, $new_change) {
    $query->where(DB::raw('json_extract(old_value, "$.theme_id") = 1))
        ->orWhere(DB::raw('json_extract(new_value, "$.theme_id") = 1));
```

Should be:

```
->where(function($query) use ($other_key, $new_change) {
    $query->where(DB::raw("json_extract(old_value, '$.theme_id')"), 1);
        ->orWhere(DB::raw("json_extract(new_value, '$.theme_id')"), 1);
```

That's how the where statements in Laravel work. I did not insert a second parameter and that's why Laravel assumed I was checking for NULL. It works now, sorry for my stupidity.