# Search and Filter input value with backend nested json data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

[this screenshot represents the table on which I am performing the opration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR5qZ.png)

I am working on laravel Ecommerce REST API's and API is for Filter.  Whatever user will filter it should be searched in the backend **meta_key** column **(which contains deep nested json)** and should return the matching records.

I tried below:-

```
Parameter receiving from mobile side:- 
**(below params can be either or)**
1.$brand = $request->brand;
2.$size = $request->brand;
3.$color = $request->brand;
4.$rating = $request->brand;

$sql = ProductsMeta::where('meta_value','LIKE','%'.$brand.'%')
         ->orWhere('meta_value','LIKE','%'.$color.'%')
         ->orWhere('meta_value','LIKE','%'.$size.'%')
         ->orWhere('meta_value','LIKE','%'.$rating.'%');
```

This doesn't return record as excepted.

I also, tried using **FIND_IN_SET()** method. but, this also doesn't work for me.

Will you please suggest me to get this resolve?

Comment: Which type has `meta_value` in DB? string or json object?

Comment: So what is `$request->brand` and why the `1. 2. 3. 4.` ?? Is that really in the code

Comment: take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023802/my-where-statement-with-a-json-extract-function-on-a-nullable-column-is-confirme

Comment: @V-K Its longtext datatype and json object

Comment: @RiggsFolly, 1.2.3.4 is just the series of param. Do not consider that series.